# Costume rounding numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, decimal

I want to round some numbers in SQL Server like this: If the number after the comma under then 500 I want to make 500 and if the number more then 500 I want add one and make the number after dot 0

> Example
> **1.020
> I want to make it 1.500 and 1.501 I want to make it 2.000**

Comment: Possibly "costume" is meant to be "custom"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

You can use **% Modulo Operator** to Separate the Decimal Values from an Interger,

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE([value]  DECIMAL(9,3));

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES (1.020),(1.501),(0.250),(0.680);


SELECT *,CASE WHEN [value]%1>0.500 THEN CAST([value] AS INT)+1.000 ELSE  CAST([value] AS INT)+0.500 END
FROM @DataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value]  DECIMAL(9,3)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES (1.020)
      ,(1.501)
      ,(0.250)
      ,(0.680);

SELECT [value]
      ,CAST
       (
           CAST([value] AS INT) 
           +
           CASE WHEN [value] * 1000 % 1000 > 500
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0.5
           END
           AS DECIMAL(9,3)
       ) AS [new_value]
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

The idea is to get the value after the dot and to compare it with 500. Then, add `1` or `0.5` to the value before the dot.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `ROUND()` and `CEILING()` functions such as

```
SELECT nr,CASE WHEN nr=ROUND(nr,0) 
               THEN nr 
               ELSE CASE WHEN ROUND(nr,0)=ROUND(nr,1) THEN
                              CEILING(ROUND(nr,1)*15)/10 
                         ELSE ROUND(nr,0)
                          END
                END AS rounded_nr
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b2fdec6d67c456b5b0d81a4ff2b26ae)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to round up to the next .000 or .500 value.

For rounding up you can use the [CEILING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql) function. However, that rounds to the next integer value.

When you want to support halves, then multiplied by 2 you get whole values. So first multiply by 2, then round up. And divide the result again to get the correct value:

```sql
SELECT columnToRoundUp, CEILING(columnToRoundUp*2)/2 as RoundedValue
FROM (
          SELECT 1.20 as columnToRoundUp
    UNION SELECT 2.49
    UNION SELECT 3.50
    UNION SELECT 4.51
    UNION SELECT 5.70
    UNION SELECT 6.99
    UNION SELECT 7.00) a
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/103985)